# Does the Manifester Weapon allows a psionic character to have more power points than max?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, psionics

> Power (Daily): Minor Action.  You gain
>   1 power point until the end of your
>   next turn.  You can use this power
>   point only to augment a psionic attack
>   power.

Does that mean if a character has 6 out of 6 power points and they use this daily power, they will then have 7 out of 6 power points until the end of their next turn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that in this case yes you would end up having more power points than your max. This is not a "house rule," it is the way that this item works. It does not say `regain` it says `gain`. Therefore, no matter how many power points you have, you gain 1 extra one that does not count against your max. You would really have 6/6 and 1 from the weapon not 7/6.

(though I don't think it would be wise to use the Item daily power at the start of a combat, jest so you can show off you seven power points.)

Comment: I think that is a great interpretation.  Is the technical distinction you make between "gain" and "regain" explicated anywhere in core materials that you know of?

Comment: I could see using it as part of an alpha-strike setup at the start of combat, actually. If the character is planning on APing next turn, it's a good component of a "I'm going to expend way too many resources" move.

Comment: @ chaos: I have not encountered anything that says otherwise, I know that for healing that the terminology is always regain which is does not allow for over the maximum. I could not find the rules on Power Points, but it was more the wording of the item power, It trumps the normal ruling anyway.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

As per [Psion](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=437):

> Power Points: You start with 2 power points. You gain 2 additional power points at 3rd and 7th level, 1 additional power point at 13th level, and 2 additional power points at 17th, 21st, 23rd, and 27th level. If you gain power points from another source (such as your paragon path), add them to your power point total. You can use your power points to augment any augmentable power you have, regardless of how you gained the power.

This item adds (very briefly) to your power-point total, rather than the pool. Giving you 7 out of 7 power points. Furthermore, as the player can derive no real advantage from this beyond the free power point from the weapon, there are no balance issues to consider.